# To analyze logical form of $ \{n^2 + n + 1 \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\} \subseteq \{2n+1\mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

$$ \{n^2 + n + 1 \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\} \subseteq \{2n+1\mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

$$\forall x (\exists n \in \mathbb{N} (x = n^2+n+1) \rightarrow (\exists m \in \mathbb{N}(x =2m+1))) $$

Textbook solution is $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \: \exists m \in \mathbb{N}(n^2+n+1=2m+1)$. How to go from my solution to this one ?

Comment: Is there a reason that you're expressing this so formally? People don't ordinarily think purely in terms of logical symbols, and thinking mechanically like that can actually prevent you from seeing math in more intuitive, human ways that are conducive to generating ideas for proofs.

Answer (score 0):

$$n^2 + n + 1 = n(n+1) + 1$$
In last sum first member is even, so all sum odd.